# searching a word with a particular character in it in perl

Tags: perl

am trying to search a word where it starts with any character (Capital letter) but ends with zero in perl.
For example

```
ABC0
XYZ0
EIU0
QW0
```

What I have tried -

```
$abc =~ /^[A-Z].+0$/
```

But I am not getting proper output for this. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work :

```
$abc =~ /\b[A-Z].*0\b/
```

\b matches word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` anchores at the start of a string, the `$` at the end. `.+` matches as many non-newline-characters as possible. Therefore

```
"ABC0 XYZ0 EIU0 QW0" =~ /^[A-Z].+0$/
```

matches the *whole* string.

The `\b` assertion matches at word edges: everywhere a word character and a non-word-character are adjacent. The `\w` charclass holds only word characters, the `\S` charclass all non-space-characters. Either of these is better than `.`.

So you may want to use `/\b[A-Z]\W*0\b/`.